# MacBook Pro external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

How many external displays does a Macbook Pro 13-inch 2016 model support?

Comment: you mean simultaneously ?

Comment: I mean, can i plug in 3 external monitors at the same time?

Comment: did you read this apple article ? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256

Comment: yes, and it does not say how many monitors you can use at the same time.

Comment: 2 monitors 4k resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It used to be simple where each model has a “you get one display, you get two” but now with the 4k and 5k displays, one display can have more pixels than the 6 displays Mac Pro used to support.

Also, support is a vague term sometimes. Apple “supports” less displays than you can often connect since support means fast refresh, low likelihood of lags and slowdowns and glitches as opposed to “you’ll never get signal on this mess of adapters and cables and usb drivers and daisy chained devices”

That being said, here are the articles on multiple displays:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154

> These Thunderbolt-3 capable Mac computers support multiple Thunderbolt displays:
>
> - MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) and later supports up to four Thunderbolt displays using Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapters or daisy-chaining.
> - MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) and later and MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 Ports) and later support up to two Thunderbolt displays using Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapters and daisy-chaining.

So you should expect two attached displays to run well unless there’s a 4/5k issue:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207448 (likely only one 5k for 13 inch MBP)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207447 (probably no issue with 2 4k)

Comment: so this means i cant run 3 1920x1080 displays on it right?

Comment: @sparklypanda Not necessarily. Apple isn't going to commit that it works on  an official, published KB article, but it might just work - especially if you close the lid on the MacBook. Also - there are several models of 2016 MacBook Pro - I would expect the one with the 4 ports and touch bar to be slightly more powerful in the GPU, but I could be wrong.